# Does meet of two partitions of a set always exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\Omega$ be any set. Let $\mathcal{P_1}$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ be partitions of $\Omega$. By $P_i(\omega)$ we denote cell of partition $i$ containing $\omega$.

Meet of partitions $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ is defined in the following way:

$\mathcal{P}_1\wedge \mathcal{P}_2$ is the finest partition of $\Omega$ such that $P_i(\omega)\subset (\mathcal{P}_1\wedge \mathcal{P}_2)(\omega)$ for $i=1,2$ and every $\omega\in\Omega$.

By $(\mathcal{P}_1\wedge \mathcal{P}_2)(\omega)$ we denote a cell of $\mathcal{P}_1\wedge \mathcal{P}_2$ containing $\omega$.

My question is:

Is existence of $\mathcal{P}_1\wedge \mathcal{P}_2$ always guaranteed? Is it unique? ($\Omega$ can be finite, countable or uncountable).

In the worst case (when there are no finer partitions), $\{\Omega\}$ is always meet. Is that enough to prove existence? How can i prove uniqness?

Comment: Yes. Partitions form a complete lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a,b\in\Omega$ say $a\sim b$ if there exist finitely many elements $x_0=a,x_1, \ldots , x_n=b$ such that $x_{i+1}\in \mathcal P_1(x_i)\cup \mathcal P_2(x_i)$ for $0\le i<n$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\Omega$ and the corresponding partition has the desired property. Also, any other partition with the desired property must be coarser because for any sequence $x_0,\ldots, x_n$ as above we need that all $x_i$ are in the same cell.

Comment: We say that a partition $X$ is finer than $Y$ if $|X|>|Y|$, true?

Comment: @luka5z: No. $X$ is finer than $Y$ if each member of $Y$ is a union of members of $X$.

Comment: I still don't quite get the proof of Hagen von Eitzen...

Comment: Let the partition $P$ be defined by the following sets: $P(w):=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} Q_k(w)$, where
$Q_1(w):=P_1(w)\cup P_2(w)$ and $Q_{k+1}(w):=\bigcup_{x\in Q_k(w)}P_1(x)\cup P_2(w)$. This is the partition 
corresponding to the equivalence relation mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about a partition as being induced from an equivalence relation, then we know that if $E_1,E_2$ are two equivalence relations then there is no reason for $E_1\cup E_2$ to be an equivalence relation.

However, $E_1\cup E_2$ is a reflexive and symmetric relation. So if we take $E$ to be its transitive closure, then $E$ is the smallest equivalence relation which includes both $E_1$ and $E_2$.

And it's not hard to see why $E$ induces the wanted partition. Of course that for $i=1,2$, if $a\mathrel{E_i}b$ then $a\mathrel{E}b$; and if $E'$ is an equivalence relation which has the above property then it must contain $E$, so $E$ is indeed the smallest.

This is effectively what Hagen von Eitzen suggested, although I agree it's not as clear when thinking about it in terms of partitions.

Comment: I was never good with directions, so maybe this is the join rather than the meet. If that's the case, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let $P_1=\{\{a\},\{b,c\},\{d\}\}, P_2=\{\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\}\}$ be partitions. Then meet $P_1 \wedge P_2 = \{\{a,b,c\},\{d\}\}$. I wonder if there is any way of proving it without refering to relations, ie. using definition of meet (in the first post) and definition of partition.

Comment: Okay, so we're on the same page. As for proving this directly, you can probably make some argument about $\{S_i\cup T_j\mid S_i\in P_1, T_j\in P_2, S_i\cap T_j\neq\varnothing\}$ being the wanted partition. Or something like that...

Comment: Thanks for explaining Hagen's idea. I get what you both mean now. But I still seek any proof of existence and uniqueness without relations.  In case of finite $\Omega$ it is quite obvious.

Comment: Asaf, I think the set family u posted in comment is not necessarily a partition. Or am I stupid?

Comment: It's probably not a partition. I said "something like that", you probably need to handle this slightly more with care, but essentially you have to take the union of all cells which have overlaps. So probably for each $S_i$ you take the smallest family of $T_j$'s which cover it, or something. I'm not sure, and I had a long day. In any case, you can draw the basic intuition from the proof I gave here, to understand how the partition behaves when we add more pairs to the equivalence relations and then figure it out.

Comment: I get it, u are right. I need to do sth along that lines. I will post my results if i get to some point.